# Short expression $\frac{x^2-y^2}{x(x-y)}+\frac{x^2-y^2}{x(x+y)}$

Tags: fractions

I tried to short this expression: 
$$\frac{x^2-y^2}{x(x-y)}+\frac{x^2-y^2}{x(x+y)}$$

The result should be $2$ but I get:
\begin{align}
&\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2-xy}+\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+xy}\\
=& \frac{y^2}{yx}+\frac{-y^2}{yx}\\
=&0
\end{align}

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not find a common denominator before adding the fractions since $x^2-xy\neq x^2+xy$. Moreover, you cannot add fractions 'top to bottom', that is 
$$
\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{4} \neq \frac{3}{7}
$$
this is why we find the common denominator. Try finding the common denominator first, it will be ....

> $x(x-y)(x+y)$

and then adding your fractions.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know how you got from $\frac{x²−y²}{x²−yx}$ to $\frac{y^2}{xy}$,

but fractions just don't work that way. To add those, you need a common denominator. Here you could use $x(x-y)(x+y)$, but it's a lot faster to note that $x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$ and then simplify both fractions so that they get common denominator $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, $$\frac{x^2-y^2}{x(x-y)}+\frac{x^2-y^2}{x(x+y)}=\frac{x^2-y^2}{x}\left(\frac{1}{x-y}+\frac{1}{x+y}\right)=\frac{x^2-y^2}{x}\left(\frac{x+y+x-y}{(x+y)(x-y)}\right)\\=\frac{(x-y)(x+y)}{x}\left(\frac{2x}{(x+y)(x-y)}\right)=2,~~~x\neq0,~~x\neq\pm y$$

Comment: $\ddot\smile +1$

Answer (score 1):

Start simplifying:
$$
\frac{x^2-y^2}{x(x-y)}+\frac{x^2-y^2}{x(x+y)}=
\frac{(x-y)(x+y)}{x(x-y)}+\frac{(x-y)(x+y)}{x(x+y)}=
\frac{x+y}{x}+\frac{x-y}{x}=\dots
$$